I need help to fix my pinescript for asian strategy
I think Trade Entries logic is not wrong so Strategy Tester is not response because caution This strategy did not generate any orders throughout the testing range.
I want to fix Trade Entrires logic and solve problem about "caution This strategy did not generate any orders throughout the testing range."

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
